# XCode Push to AWS CodeCommit -> Unknown Error Occurred

Tags: xcode, git, xcode7, aws-codecommit

I have set up a git repository using AWS CodeCommit.  I can push, pull, etc from the terminal with success.  I can also pull in Xcode with success.  I am using SSH for the protocol.

When I try to push, Xcode presents a prompt saying "An unknown error occurred."  There are no other details available.

The odd part is that the code seems to be pushing correctly to the repository.

I don't like receiving an error message because it leaves me apprehensive that there might actually be a problem at some point in the future that I might overlook.

Is there a way to troubleshoot and/or solve this error message?

Comment: Hey! I am facing the same issue. If you figured it please let me know. I will do the same.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm still getting the error, but everything seems to be pushing alright.  Hopefully somebody answers.  If I find a solution first, I will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a bug in XCode.  After updating to XCode 8, the problem is solved.

Comment: Still seeing this in Xcode 10.1 after migration to CodeCommit. Terminal working fine.